# Jquery DataTable next page form submit problem

Tags: jquery, ajax, debugging, datatable, submit

I'm using jQuery Datatables and I'm trying to send forms with jQuery/AJAX. This is working, but I have a problem with other pages. For example pages 2 and 3 do not send data with AJAX. Please help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  formajax2(".formajax", true, "Kullanıcı Düzenle");

  function formajax2(div, pop, title) {
    $(div).submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var form = $(this);
      var url = form.attr('action');
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
          if (pop == true) {
            popup(data, title);
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: From the sound of the issue you probably need to use a delegated event handler so the `submit` event is bound to the dynamic forms you create on the subsequent pages.

Comment: for example?   thanks for reply

Comment: this is not working btw
'''
var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();
$('#datatable').on( 'page.dt', function () {
    var info = table.page.info();
    formajax2(".formajax",true,"Kullanıcı Düzenle");
    console.warn( 'Showing page: '+info.page+' of '+info.pages );
});
'''

Comment: i dont know really why this is working on fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ysj2q1ur/ and not on my localhost :D same codes.